# What is the importance of 'save' command in monerod?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monerod-commands

I am trying to sync the wallet using monerod (and was also playing with the commands) when i came to notice a "save" option when i type 'help'. what is the use of it or is there any use of it because the blockchain will be automatically saved by monerod, right?

Answer (score 2):

The blockchain is indeed automatically saved.
This command ask to the underlying OS to write any cache to the disk immediately, when the OS has the ability to store data in cache before writing.
It's a security step you might need in extreme cases (like power loss and short UPS period).